# Can't find Controller in MVC 3 project - NotFound error

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, controller, global-asax, file-not-found, maproute

I have this global.asax file with this code:

```
routes.MapRoute("Invitations", 
                        "api/invitations", 
                        new { controller = "Invitations", action = "Invitation"});
```

And I have a Controller:

```
public class InvitationsController : Controller
{
    [HttpPut]
    public JsonResult Invitation(InvitationResponse invitationResponse)
    {
        //code
    }
}
```

And I'm accessing the controllers by HttpWebRequest with this URL:

```
"http://localhost:6055/API/Invitations"
```

When I run this I get the error "NotFound".

EDIT:

The whole global route:

routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

```
        routes.MapRoute("Users",
                        "api/users/{id}",
                        new { controller = "Users", action = "UserAction", id = UrlParameter.Optional });


        routes.MapRoute("CheckIn",
                        "api/checkins",
                        new { controller = "CheckIn", action = "CheckIn" });

        routes.MapRoute("Appointments",
                        "api/appointments/{id}",
                        new { controller = "Appointments", action = "Appointment", id = UrlParameter.Optional });

        routes.MapRoute("UserAppointments",
                        "api/users/{userId}/appointments/{startDate}",
                        new { controller = "Appointments", action = "UserAppointments", startDate = UrlParameter.Optional });

        routes.MapRoute("UserInvitations",
                        "api/users/{userId}/invitations",
                        new { controller = "Invitations", action = "UserInvitations" });

        routes.MapRoute("UserOverview",
                        "api/users/{id}/overview",
                        new { controller = "Users", action = "Overview" });

        routes.MapRoute("Invitations", 
                        "api/invitations", 
                        new { controller = "Invitations", action = "Invitation"});

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );
```

Comment: I don't know if [this tester](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/03/13/url-routing-debugger.aspx) works on MVC3 (it works on MVC2) but you can try it, it's a great tool for testing your route configuration.

Comment: I tested the tester and i get that it mathes the current request

Comment: Then your routes seem to be configured correctly, and your request should hit the controller/action. It the request not matching any other route that is higher in the route hierarchy?

Comment: Those routes is all im using. Do you see any route that is higher in the hierarchy?

Comment: MVC matches the requests with the routes in order, so for instance if you place a general route (like "Default") before (that is, place the code at the top of the route configuration). MVC will match that first. The questions was if, in the tester, your "/API/Invitations" is not matching other route that comes before your "Invitations" route?

Comment: Nope, /API/Invitations is first

Answer (score 0):

"http://localhost:6055/API/Invitations" doesn't look correct, shouldn't it be

"http://localhost:6055/**YourApp**/API/Invitations"

Comment: No im using HttpPut in this case. what i dont show is that i send a InvitationResponse objekt with the put

Comment: ah okay, I got that wrong.  have you anything else in your routes that might conflict?  have you a test for this route?

Comment: I have edited the question, so that you can se all the routes

Comment: i've tested that route in both directions, i.e. does action create correct url and does url map to corret action.  They both work.  Should you not have an application name in there between :6055 and /API ?

Comment: Some of the outher routes works correctly, so the "/api/" part is right

Comment: What do you mean with "how are you generating ..."?

Comment: Do you use ActionLink or just this specifically?  Can you give the url of the home page of your application that works?